# Can I update the object found by Collection.find() in callback function of mongoose api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

Can i update the mongoose object which is currentUser into else block
my code is as follows:

```
Profile.findOne({_id:req.body.id}).then((currentUser)=>{
if(currentUser.password == req.body.newPassword){
res.status(200).json({
"message": "similar to old password"
});
}
else{
res.status(200).json({
"message": "password got updated"
});
}
});
```

Comment: Yes you can. On a side note, the only way `currentUser.password == req.body.newPassword` is true is if you don't hash passwords in your database, which hopefully isn't what you're doing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, just update whatever field you want to update and then call the '.save()' method

```
Profile.findOne({ _id: req.body.id }).then((currentUser) => {
  if (currentUser.password == req.body.newPassword) {
    res.status(200).json({
      "message": "similar to old password"
    });
  }
  else {
    // update here
    currentUser.name = "test";
    // save to DB
    currentUser.save()
    res.status(200).json({
      "message": "password got updated"
    });
  }
});
```

Read more about it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)